# How can I sort a Bash output and save it to a sql db

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, terminal

I've been trying to get the data from this command `ioreg -r -c "AppleSmartBattery"` and save each one of its inputs to a sql db

> $ ioreg -r -c "AppleSmartBattery"
> +-o AppleSmartBattery  <class AppleSmartBattery, id 0x1000222c9, registered, ma$
> {
> "TimeRemaining" = 179
> "AvgTimeToEmpty" = 179
> "AdapterDetails" = {"FamilyCode"=0}
> "ChargingOverride" = 0
> "AppleRawCurrentCapacity" = 2373
> "InstantTimeToEmpty" = 154
> "AppleRawMaxCapacity" = 3811
> "ExternalChargeCapable" = No

I would need to save it to a sql table, where one column is "*" and the next one is the value after the equal
I was trying to build a "for loop", I got this far I cant figure out how to continue

```
batstat=$(ioreg -r -c "AppleSmartBattery")
for i in ${batstat[@]}; do
sed 's/^[^{]*{\([^{}]*\)}.*/\1/' $i
echo $i
done
```

I would need to accomplish the following

1. get one single value in quotes "" out each time the for goes by the line
2. assign the correct value after the equals sign to the respective quoted value

thanks :)

Comment: [Don't try to read lines with a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Something like a [`while IFS= read -r line` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) works much better. Also, `sed 's/this/that/` operates on files (or standard input), not on variables. I also recommend using [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), as it'll point out common mistakes in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's impossible, but I think doing this entirely in a shell script is a bit much when there are easier solutions available.

What I'd do here is convert the output to JSON and then use a Node module like [JSON-to-SQL](https://github.com/x4D40/json-to-sql) to generate the table from the JSON schema, and [JSON-SQL](https://github.com/2do2go/json-sql) to convert the output to an `INSERT` statement, which you can then use with any Node SQL client, like [sql-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-client).

You can also probably parse the output more cleanly and easily in Node using a module like [sh](http://shjs.tuton.fr/) to capture the `ioreg` command output, but here's what I came up with for converting the command output into valid JSON.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function parseData() {
  tail -n +2 $1 | \
  sed -re 's/\=/\:/g' | \
  sed -re 's/</\"/g' | \
  sed -re 's/>/\"/g' | \
  sed -re 's/No/false/g' | \
  sed -re 's/Yes/true/g' | \
  sed -re 's/\(/\[/g' | \
  sed -re 's/\)/\]/g' | \
  sed '$d' | \
  sed '$d' | \
  sed 's/$/,/' | \
  sed '1 s/\,//' | \
  sed '$ s/\,//' | \
  sed '52 s/,//'
}

ioreg -r -c "AppleSmartBattery" | parseData
```

The only issue is if the number of lines in the output ever changes, the `52` in the last line of the `parseData` function would need to be updated.

Comment: I see, I'll try and build it to check how it works out
thank you :)